# How to bind Java Spring time attribute to a Thymeleaf field?

Tags: java, spring, time, thymeleaf

I have a problem with Java Time Attribute binding to a Thymeleaf field.

Here is my HTML code

```
<input th:field="*{startTime}" type="text"/>
<script>
    $("#startTime").timepicker({
        showSeconds: true,
        showMeridian: false,
        secondStep: 1

    });
</script>
```

Here is my model attribute code

```
@NotNull(message = "Start time cannot be empty")
private Time startTime;

public Time getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public void setStartTime(Time startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}
```

When I submit the form I got the exception

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
type java.sql.Time for property startTime; nested exception is
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
convert from type java.lang.String to type
@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Time
for value 14:15:41; nested exception is
org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "14:15:41":
Value 14 for clockhourOfHalfday must be in the range [1,12]
```

If I insert 12 hr time I got this exception

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.sql.Time for property startTime; nested exception is
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Time for value 11:15:41; nested exception is
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type org.joda.time.DateTime to type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Time
```

How to bind Spring Time Attribute to a Thymeleaf field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Property type String and create get set method and bind to view

```
private String startTimeString;
```

And controller side Convert value  String to Time and Set it

```
setStartTime(Time.valueOf(ModelName.getstartTimeString()));
```